# Show that the image of a linear map is a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that the image of the following linear map is a plane and find its equation:
$f(x,y,z)=(3x+y-2z,-2x+5y+z,x+6y-z)$

**Attempt at solving the problem:**
$$
\left\{
 \begin{array}{rcr}
  3x+y-2z = & x' \\
  -2x+5y+z = & y'\\
  x+6y-z = & z' \\
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

After using the gauss method I get:
$x'+y'-5z'+z=0$

So my question is: Is that the equation of the plane or should I change x';y';z' to their equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not the equation of a plane because you have the variable, z, as well as x', y', z'.  It is difficult to give a proof without knowing what **definition** or characterization of "plane" you are using.

I would start they way you did, letting x'= 3x+ y- 2z, y'= -2x+ 5y+ z, and z'= x+ 6y- z.  Adding the last two equations, y'+ z'= -x+ 11y, eliminating z, and adding the first equation to **twice** the first also eliminates z, x'+ 2y'= -x+ 11y.  That happens to be exactly the same as before so x'+ 2y'= y'+ z' or x'+ y'- z'= 0.  That is the equation of this plane.

Comment: But would it be incorrect to say that the equation of the plane is: $x'+y'-5z'+z=0  so -4x-24y+5z=0$?